# Understanding import, providers,exports and controller in nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MailService (MailerService, ?, CreateSendMailDto). Please make sure that the argument EmailRepository at index [1] is available in the MailModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If EmailRepository is a provider, is it part of the current MailModule?
- If EmailRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MailModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing EmailRepository */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MailService (MailerService, ?, CreateSendMailDto). Please make sure that the argument EmailRepository at index [1] is available in the MailModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If EmailRepository is a provider, is it part of the current MailModule?
- If EmailRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MailModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing EmailRepository */ ]
  })
```

I'm new to nestjs thou not too experienced with nodejs. Pls i need someone to help me understand the context of module export and providers. I don't really know what to export, import, provied or put in controller, i understand some few stuff but i seek full undersanding of how and what is really happening there. Thanks

Comment: Have u tried reading the documentation? Show your code that would help to understand your case

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the code producing the error, but I'll try to explain it in simple terms, assuming the following scenario:

- You have two resources, Vehicle & Driver, and you want to use DriverService in VehicleService.

Solution:

- Export DriverService from  `driver.module.ts`
- Then import DriverModule in  `vehicle.module.ts`

---

```
@Module({
  controllers: [DriverController],
  providers: [DriverService],
  exports: [DriverService]
})

@Module({
  imports:[DriverModule]
  controllers: [VehicleController],
  providers: [VehicleService],
})
```

---

You can visit [the NestJs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules) for more info.